# Laravel store multiple just saves one

Tags: php, laravel

I am sending array of data to controller but it only saves 1 row to database, I need to save multiple rows (depend on array length).

## Code

`controller`

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::guard('api')->user();

    $transit = new Transit;
    foreach($request->input('serials') as $serial){ //looping my serials array for each row
        if(!empty($serial['barcode_id'])) { // filter out empty objects from array
            $barcode = Barcode::where('serial_number', $serial['barcode_id'])->orWhere('u_serial_number', $serial['barcode_id'])->first();
            $transit->barcode_id = $barcode['id'];
            $transit->transNu = mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999);
        }
    }
    $transit->from_id = $request->input('from_id');
    $transit->to_id = $request->input('to_id');
    $transit->sender_id = $user->id;
    $transit->description = $request->input('description');
    if($transit->save()){
        DB::table('outlet_products')->where('barcode_id', $transit->barcode_id)->update(['outlet_id' => null]);
    }
    return response()->json([
        'data' => $transit,
        'message' => 'Transit data saved successfully.'
    ]);
}
```

## Screenshot

`request data`

[image: one]

`stored data`

[image: two]

**any idea?**

Comment: If I'm not missing something, `save` seems to be outside foreach. Only the last item out of the two that does not get filtered will be saved.

Comment: As I can see you're saving only once after creating the object. Can you confirm?

Comment: `$barcode->save();` is missing , but actually you just call ` $barcode = Barcode::where...` but did not insert any data here.

Comment: @user3532758 even with moving my save inside foreach it still saves only one of the objects

Comment: @OMiShah sorry didn't catch your point i just explain again to make sure, i have 2 objects in my sample screenshot and i want to save both but it only saves one of them

Comment: @sta I don't want to save anything in `$barcode` table I want to save data in `transits` table.

Comment: Let's check by moving`$transit = new Transit;` inside foreach as well. End of foreach to right before returning the response.

Comment: @user3532758 I just did that and it worked :) thanks <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `$transit = new Transit;` inside the foreach, and end the foreach loop right before returning the response.

What happens in the current setup is that during the first iteration, a transit object is is created and when it gets saved, it will get an id. So for the second/and subsequent iterations, the Transit object will have an `id` and calling save will perform an `update` operation on the record with that id.

Moving it inside foreach will always give you a new empty `Transit` object and saving will give you a new record.